# How to modify the style xml file from programmatically android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am try to change the action bar background color for whole application but it required change in every activity. That why i want change style.xml file from my java code is there any way to this.please reply thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ActionBar background color programmatically:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
```

A good way would be to save your colors to `res\colors.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="actionbar1">#FF6666</color>
    <color name="actionbar2">#28B0DF</color>
</resources>
```

And then set your ActionBar background like this:

```
int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.actionbar1);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

Comment: thanks it work but I have to change it in all the activity in my application. is there any way to handle it one time